# Using an object.function(argument)

Tags: java

So, in one of my class assignments, I have to create a function for a book that prints the book title with a prefix.

But since the book isn't an argument to this function, I don't see how to "access" the title. If it were an argument, for example, to a function `print(prefix, book)` I could call `system.out.print(prefix + book)`, but since it comes before the function I have no idea how to do it (I'm a beginner programmer).

Comment: This function, defined in a class, is called a "method"

Comment: Yes, and that "method" will have access to the fields of the instance of the Book class. So if you have a field called `title`, you can use `System.out.println(prefix + this.title)` in your print method.

Comment: "*[...] any suggestions?*" - [Oracle's lesson on Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand  you have to write a `print` method in the class Book, so you can use it as:

```
 Book myBook = new Book ("Alice's adventures etc");
 myBook.print("Myfavorite");
```

First, the Book class probably has fields for the informations:

```
 class Book {
      String title;                     // field
      Book(String t) { title = t; }     // constructor sets initial field values
      ...
 }
```

and then methods have access to these fields :

```
 class Book {
      String title;
      ...
      void print(String prefix) {
          System.out.println(prefix + " " + title);   // uses field
      }
 ...
 }
```